# "Рваные края" при border-radius

Tags: html, css

Делаю пагинацию, заметил, что края у кнопок получаются какими-то рваными, неровными. Вот пример (первый вариант - то, как оно выглядит у меня, второй - то как по идее должно быть):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}
.block {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #5f5f5f;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.block1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #5f5f5f;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.block1:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="block">

  </div>
  <div class="block1">

  </div>
</div>
```

У кого какие мысли на этот счет? Прошу помочь.

Comment: браузер так отрисовывает. используйте картинки для идеальных кружков. надо выбирать между производительность и красотой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, поразмыслив немного пришел к выводу, что в случаях некорректной отрисовки браузером бордера при border-radius, наиболее оптимальным будет использование псевдоэлемента с фоном и абсолютным позиционированием. В коде ниже первая ссылка сделана обычным бордером, вторая - методом, который я описал выше:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: url('http://ios.freepps.top/images/adaptive/body.png') repeat;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 70px auto;
}
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5f5f5f;
  border: 1px solid #5f5f5f;
}
.block1 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: #5f5f5f;
  border-radius: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5f5f5f;
  z-index: 10;
}
.block1:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  background: url('http://ios.freepps.top/images/adaptive/body.png');
  border-radius: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a class="block" href="#close">
    1
  </a>
  <a class="block1" href="#close">
    2
  </a>
</div>
```